# Unable to create web site project using VS 2010

Tags: sql, visual-studio

[Here is My current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2i6V.jpg)Trying to create my first website using Visual Studio 2010. I configured IIS, installed ASP.NET MVC4 (not sure if I need it though). But still unable to see anything when clicking Visual Basic or VisualC#.  What am I missing?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try: New -> Project. You should get more options there.

Comment: Do you need 2010 for any specific reason?

Comment: Not really. But I am using SQL Server 2012. So VS 2010 is my free reporting tool.

Comment: So your download of SQL Server 2012 came with VS2010? Maybe try uninstalling VS2010 and reinstalling from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23507

Comment: But are you sure it will resolve the issue? What is the exact reason for that? Do you know?

Comment: There are no template projects installed for VS2010 on your machine right now. Otherwise they would be showing up in the templates. Either they didn't come with your install or somehow missed to install during setup which I doubt so I believe it didn't come with your install. No, I'm not sure it will resolve 100% but that would be my first step to try and resolve unless you can find the template files online, download them, and put them in the correct folder for VS2010 to grab. Or... reboot if you haven't done so.

Comment: Were you able to get it to work?

Comment: I'm trying to find templates online and understand more about this issue. Seems like standard edition just doesnt have it.  Haven't try to reinstall VS2010 yet.

Comment: Whoops, accidentally sent the wrong link in case you end up having to reinstall: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691

Comment: My current version is SP1Rel  . I attached picture at the top

Comment: I installed Visual Studio 2015, like you recommended. But now I am not able to open my old SSRS projects, because I deleted VS2010. 
Also, can I use VS2015 to build regular SSRS reports? I dont see it in "Projects". Thanks